# Extending hello_chat: howto mimic session-wide variables

Tags: opa

I'm extending hello_chat from Opa book chapter 1 to familiarise myself with Opa.  Here's what I've done so far: [extended hello_chat on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/Pb7VmcqH).

The problem:
When a user sends a message I want to show "YOU: blah blah blah" in the same user's view and "USERNAME: blah blah blah" in other users' views.  But I can't figure out a way to do so.

I'd appreciate any hint/help.  TIA,

--
Bahman

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work because when user is in a room the `#user` element does not exist in the DOM anymore (it was overridden in `join_room`).

Why don't you extend `user_update` with one more parameter being the user name for whom the update is being performed? I.e. `current_user` could become a parameter of this function instead of a local binding.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how can I extend it.  Correct me if I'm wrong please: `user_update` is an observer function meaning that it is called only when there has been a broadcast. And it can take only one argument -the message that has been broadcasted.

Comment: I can see that you answered this one for yourself :)

Comment: Yes.  After reading the Opa book again and many hours of scratching head I finally found out what you meant by "extending" `user_update`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  [Partial Application](http://doc.opalang.org/index.html#_functions) did the trick.

For those who rather see the code, check [source on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/w84qLE8x)